# Fetch hash fields based on certain value among a list of fields

Tags: redis

In redis using hash, how to fetch all related fields of a key based on a condition or a field value?

Like hash key = details
details has fields name, type [student, teacher], class, section, etc.

I need to get all details [hash key] fields when type == "Student" eliminating fields with type teacher?

What property can be used in redis?

Answer (score 5):

Redis is not a relational database system, there is no implicit management of secondary indexes, there is no way you can retrieve an object based on the value of a hash field.

With Redis you need to materialize your access paths. If you need to index by type, then you have to build a set (one per type value) to reference all your objects.